Alternate proof of non-monotonicity of Brownian motion
I am reading Chapter 14 of Measure Theory, Probability, and Stochastic Processes, by Le Gall. I am new to Brownian motion.
I believe there is a "standard" proof of the non-monotonicity of one-dimensional Brownian motion on any non-degenerate interval $[a, b]$, e.g., Theorem 1.22, p. 18, Brownian Motion by Mörters and Peres, which is discussed here.
I do not understand this (seemingly) alternate proof:

Corollary 14.11: ($d = 1$) Almost surely, the function $t \mapsto B_t$ is not monotone on any non-trivial interval.
Proof From the first assertion of Corollary 14.10 and the simple Markov property in Proposition 14.8 (iii), we get immediately that
a.s. for every rational $q \in \mathbb Q_+$, for every $\epsilon > 0$,
$$ \sup_{q \leq t \leq q + \epsilon} B_t > B_q, \qquad \inf_{q \leq t
 \leq q + \epsilon} B_t < B_q. $$ The desired result follows. Notice
that we restricted ourselves to rational values of $q$ in order to
discard a countable union of sets of zero probability (and in fact
the stated result would fail if we would consider all real values of
$q$). $\square$

For completeness:

Corollary 14.10 (first part): ($d = 1$) We have, a.s. for every $\epsilon > 0$, $$ \sup_{0 \leq s \leq \epsilon} B_s > 0, \qquad
 \inf_{0 \leq s \leq \epsilon} B_s < 0. $$


Proposition 14.8 (iii): For every $s \geq 0$, the process $\left( B_t^{(s)} \right)_{t \geq 0}$ defined by $B_t^{(s)} :=B_{s + t} - B_s$
is also a Brownian motion, and the collection $\left( B_t^{(s)}
 \right)_{t \geq 0}$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s := \sigma\left(
 B_r, 0 \leq r \leq s\right)$.

My attempt:
I have a pseudo-proof below, but I'm not convinced it's correct or complete.
Because $\left( B_t^{(s)} \right)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion, we can use Corollary 14.10 and the uniqueness of the law of Brownian motion to deduce that
$$
\mathbb P\left( \inf_{0 \leq s \leq \epsilon} B_s^{(r)} < 0\right) = 1.
$$
For any $\omega \in \Omega$, we have
$$
\inf_{0 \leq s \leq \epsilon} B_s^{(r)}(\omega) = \inf_{0 \leq s \leq \epsilon} B_{r + s}(\omega) - B_r(\omega),
$$so
$$
\left\{ \omega \in \Omega \colon \inf_{0 \leq s \leq \epsilon} B_s^{(r)} < 0 \right\} = \left\{ \omega \in \Omega \colon \inf_{0 \leq s \leq \epsilon} B_{r + s} < B_r \right\}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\mathbb P\left( \inf_{0 \leq s \leq \epsilon} B_{r + s} < B_r\right) = 1.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\mathbb P\left( \sup_{0 \leq s \leq \epsilon} B_{r + s} > B_r\right) = 1.
$$
Changing the indexing and taking the intersection,
$$
\mathbb P\left( \left\{ \inf_{0 \leq s \leq \epsilon} B_{r + s} < B_r \right\} \cap \left\{ \sup_{0 \leq s \leq \epsilon} B_{r + s} > B_r \right\}\right) = 1.
$$
Therefore, the path almost surely goes below $B_r(\omega)$ and above $B_r(\omega)$, in which case the path cannot be monotone on $[r, r + \epsilon]$.
Questions:

It doesn't seem like I used the simple Markov property anywhere. Have I made a mistake?
Loosely, it seems like I've shown that Brownian motion is almost surely not monotone on any interval $[r, r + \epsilon] \subseteq [0, \infty)$. I don't understand the part about using rational values in order to discard a countable union of sets of zero probability.


I believe you used the simple Markov property to identify the law of $B^{(r)}(s)$. For 2, you've proven that for fixed $r$, $B$ is almost surely not monotone on $[r, r + \varepsilon]$. By applying this result for every $r \in \mathbb{Q}_+$, Le Gall is able to deduce that Brownian motion is not monotonic on any interval.

@legionwhale I don't understand your first point, because according to the book, the law of Brownian motion is the same for any Brownian motion. This was dealt with before the simple Markov property. Regarding the second point, if we take $r \in \mathbb Q$ and intersect over all these events, then this shows that BM is a.s. not monotonic on any interval of length $\epsilon$ with rational left endpoint $r$. Then because any non-trivial interval $[a, b]$ contains such an $[r, r + \epsilon]$, we are done? I am not too sure.

How do you know $B^{(r)}(s)$ is a Brownian motion without the simple Markov property? I'm not sure which result you mean that was proven earlier in the book. For the second part, almost; I was trying to give a very brief description. Since not every non-trivial interval contains $[r,r+ \varepsilon]$ (for instance, an interval of width $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$), let $\varepsilon$ range over $\mathbb{Q}_+$ as well. This still describes a countable intersection, and so this gives the desired result.

@legionwhale I am looking at the book; I am not sure the simple Markov property is necessary to prove that $\left( B_s^{(r)} \right){s \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion. Perhaps I am confused. Anyway, regarding the second issue, I think you are right: any $[a, b]$ contains some $[r, r  + \epsilon]$, where both $r$ and $\epsilon$ are rational. So the probability of the intersection $\bigcap{r, \epsilon \in \mathbb Q_{\geq 0}}$ should still be one.

Yes, I think so. For the first issue, when I learnt it, the statement that $(B^{(r)}_s)$ was a  Brownian motion was exactly described as the simple Markov property, if I recall correctly.

Hmm, looking at my notes, I just checked that $B_s^{(r)}$ is a BM by verifying the definition of BM. Thanks for your help. I guess I'll think about the issue with the simple Markov property some more

No worries. Hope you figure it out.
